# in pyvis I always get this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, attributeerror, pyvis

I want to do a network visualisation using pyvis in the latest version and the python version 3.9.6:

```py
from pyvis.network import Network
g = Network()
g.add_node(0)
g.add_node(1)
g.add_edge(0, 1)
g.show('test.html')
```

every time I execute `g.show()` i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tom/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Projekte/Coding_/f1 standings/test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    g.show('nx.html')
  File "/Users/tom/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyvis/network.py", line 546, in show
    self.write_html(name, open_browser=False,notebook=True)
  File "/Users/tom/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyvis/network.py", line 515, in write_html
    self.html = self.generate_html(notebook=notebook)
  File "/Users/tom/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pyvis/network.py", line 479, in generate_html
    self.html = template.render(height=height,
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'
```

I tried updating pyvis, I changed all sorts of details in my code and I imported all of pyvis.network without any results.

Answer (score 31):

In 0.3.2 that gets pushed to pip, for some reason the `Network` `.show()` function have `notebook=True` as default, even though the `Network()` constructor has `notebook=False` as default. I changed my show function and specify `notebook=False` then it works properly again.

https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/blob/ccb7ce745ee4159ce45eac70b9848ab965fc0906/pyvis/network.py#L537

```
from pyvis.network import Network
g = Network()
g.add_node(0)
g.add_node(1)
g.add_edge(0, 1)
g.show('test.html', notebook=False)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: On a Linux distro (I'm on EndeavourOS) and with default install location (I installed with yay from the AUR), this will be located in somewhere like this `/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyvis/network.py`.

Answer (score 10):

Probably you've installed version 0.3.2.
I had same issue today, downgrading to 0.3.1 helped me

Comment: This worked for me! To install older version : `pip install pyvis==0.3.1`

Answer (score 6):

I was able to fix a similar issue, where I was running pyvis with networkx in a Jupyter Notebook.

#### The minimal code example

```
from pyvis import network as net
import networkx as nx

#%%
g=net.Network()
nxg = nx.complete_graph(5)
g.from_nx(nxg) 

#%%
g.show("example.html")
```

#### Error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'render'
```

#### Solution

When initializing the Network, I added `notebook=True`, this fixed the issue for me. The new code is:

```
from pyvis import network as net
import networkx as nx

#%%
g=net.Network(notebook=True)
nxg = nx.complete_graph(5)
g.from_nx(nxg)

#%%
g.show("example.html")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: There are "too many pending edits" so I should comment that the notebook=True term should appear on the `show` function call, and not when initializing the Network.

Comment: Adding`notebook=True` to the Network() initialization worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The default template is loaded from the pyvis package's `templates/template.html` file.  You could make sure this template is being found on disk correctly, or you could set your own template manually using `Network().set_template`

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how i can Default self.template to none? The argument of Network().set_template requires a file path given in a string. Also self.template is equal to None on default. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, the default `self.template = None`, but the default template is loaded from the package's own `templates/template.html` file.  This happens because the default `self.template_dir ~= '/templates/'` (within the pyvis package), and the default `self.path = 'template.html'`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error on macOS. **`g.show(...)`** seems to both write the html AND try to open it in your browser (unless you're in a notebook).  For me, this error seems to be related to trying to *open* the HTML file.

If I call **`g.save_graph('example.html')` instead of `g.show('example.html')`**, then the code runs without error. Both [`.save_graph()`](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/blob/ccb7ce745ee4159ce45eac70b9848ab965fc0906/pyvis/network.py#L438) and [`.show()`](https://github.com/WestHealth/pyvis/blob/ccb7ce745ee4159ce45eac70b9848ab965fc0906/pyvis/network.py#L548) call `.write_html()` internally, but `.show()` also passes the `open_browser=True` kwarg: `.write_html(open_browser=True, ...)`.

```
from pyvis.network import Network
g = Network()
g.add_node(0)
g.add_node(1)
g.add_edge(0, 1)
# g.show('test.html')
g.save_graph('test.html')
```